# How to read from a csv in as an array?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to do something specific (create networks via APIs) but I am missing some basic python knowledge to do so. Essentially the API requires that the input be structured in a certain way, specifically that the field productTypes be an array. I am getting the following error:

`{'errors': ["'productTypes' must be an array"]}`

This makes perfect sense, but the problem is that I am reading this information from a csv file as shown in the code below, so could anyone guide me on how I can convert the input being read from the csv file into an array? Is there a function function I should use to convert this or can I just edit the syntax to let python know this should be an array (and if so how)?

I am using python 3.7 and my code is shown below.

```
with open('provision.csv', 'r') as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(new_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        dashboard.organizations.createOrganizationNetwork(
            org_id,
            name = line['name'],
            productTypes = line['productTypes'],
            tags = line['tags'],
            timeZone = line['timeZone'],
            notes = line['notes']
        )
```

[Here is an image of the csv.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quFPK.png)

When trying `list(line['productTypes'])` as suggested I am getting the following error:

```
meraki.exceptions.APIError: organizations, createOrganizationNetwork - 400 Bad Request, {'errors': ["Each element in 'productTypes' must be one of: 'wireless', 'appliance', 'switch', 'systemsManager', 'camera', 'cellularGateway' or 'environmental'"]}
```

Please view below an example of what the API call expects as an input (the example given by the company themselves)

What I am trying to do differently is run a loop to call this many times and read the info from a csv.

```
organization_id = '549236'
name = 'Long Island Office'
product_types = ['appliance', 'switch', 'camera']

response = dashboard.organizations.createOrganizationNetwork(
    organization_id, name, product_types, 
    tags=['tag1', 'tag2'], 
    timeZone='America/Los_Angeles', 
    notes='Combined network for Long Island Office'
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Depends on how the `productTypes` part of your CSV file looks like. Add an example to the question.

Comment: The file is just plain text.

Comment: The API expects you to pass a list in `productTypes`. So what do you have in your CSV file that will be required to be made into an array? What does `line['productTypes']` look like? And what should the corresponding parameter to the API call look like? Add all this information to the question please.

Comment: The line `productTypes = line['productTypes']` turns `productTypes ` into whatever value that key has in the dictionary (which appears to be a string) — so the error you say you are getting makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split()` method to create a list, for example here : `productTypes = line['productTypes'].split()`.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the type of thing I was looking for. Upon trying this I am getting the following error:

```
{'errors': ["Each element in 'productTypes' must be one of: 'wireless', 'appliance', 'switch'
```

This is strange because i have triple checked my csv and indeed the elements are as requested

Comment: Could you edit your post with the full error message ?

Comment: @AliImran you can also try printing productTypes and show us the output

Comment: Sure thing when I try to do `print(line['productTypes'])` I get the text wireless followed by switch in the next line (which is reflected by what is in the csv)

Comment: Juste paste it in here please :) You can also try using `repr()` or `type()` to analyse what you get

Comment: When I print it returns:  
wireless  
switch,  and when I use print type() it returns `<class 'str'>`

Comment: @AliImran see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. i did manage to figure it out. Had to use split() because it seperates at the word level while list() seperates at the letter level

Comment: Nice to hear ! I updated my answer.